# domain name system - rDNS is not exist

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, reverse-dns, ptr-record

I need some help with Reverse DNS as I have got a problem with it. I have setup rDNS on my hosting provider which I use rdns1.example.com and I have a server hostname which it is gateway1.example.com. I want to use both different name to get it separate because of the email providers that want to see both different names so my email would go to inbox.

When I open on the Email Deliverability software through in the cpanel, I can see this:

[https://i.imgur.com/xMDWE4R.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWbwf.png)

Can you please advice me with what I need to do?

How I can match with the rDNS?

Do I need to change the server hostname to match with the rDNS or what?

I want to use smtp513.example.com to send the email and I want to use gateway1.example.com to get access to whm and cpanel. I am not sure what I need to do so I need your help with this.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set reverse DNS records yourself, even if you have a web hosting software that claims to provide the service. These can only be set by the owner of the IP addresses. You will need to contact your service provider for assistance with changing reverse DNS records.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but what I am asking is does the rDNS have to be matching with the hostname of the server or it have to be separate?

Comment: For email, they must be the same, and ideally should be a subdomain of your domain from which you are sending mail.

Comment: oh right, so I want to use smtp513.mydomain.com and my hostname is gateway1.mydomain.com so do i have to change from rdns1.mydomain.com to gateway1.mydomain.com in the rDNS records?

Comment: That sounds right, I think. It's a little hard to say, since you're still using fake information.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer indicates, you can't do it yourself in your self-hosted cpanel system.  Your VPS provider control panel, possibly.  Otherwise put in a support ticket.

As to what to set things to, whatever name your mail server uses in the HELO process (I use `smtp.example.com`) should be used in all things related to mail, mail delivery, and mail security.  IE, whatever IP address the connection appears to come from should have its rDNS set to `smtp.example.com` (I mention this in case someone is NATing/port forwarding for some reason). The SPF records, SSL certificate, etc should all reference the `smtp.example.com` hostname.

Comment: Oh right, well I want to use two different IPs to point it in PTR in a single hostname but I cant now because the PTR will only allow you to setup with one IP in a single hostname. I want to setup two different smtp addresses that come with two different IPs, e.g: 106.x.xx.59 and 106.xxx.xxx.202 as the 106.x.xx.59 will be using for smtp513 and 106.xxx.xxx.202 will be using for smtp516 as a backup. The other way I could do is buy another VPS to transfer the IP and point it to PTR that match with the hostname. I am sure someone on here might know better than I do?

Comment: @RobertJones plenty. What is the issue? One ip can point to one name.  Many ips can point to the same name.  Many names can point to one ip.

Comment: Please read what I said. I cant add 2 different ips in the ptr record using single hostname. I want to setup two different ips e.g: 1.2.3.4 and 1.2.3.20 to add it in the ptr records as I want to do this send the marketing emails. If one IP get blocked I can use another smtp address to send the email. Do you know what I need to do?

Comment: Do I need to get another server to add the ip that match with the hostname and the ptr record?

Comment: I want the ip 1.2.3.4 to resolve to server1 and 1.2.3.20 to resolve to server2. How I can do that using a single hostname?

Comment: If it is not possible then it sound like to me I would need to get another server to point the ip 1.2.3.20 to server2 and add the server2 hostname in the rdns as long I have the current server that point the ip to 1.2.3.4 that I already added the server1 hostname in the ptr record.

Comment: @RobertJones at least i know how dns works and what values need to be set where.

Comment: If you know how dns works and if you know how I can use both ips 1.2.3.4 to resolve to server1 and 1.2.3.20 to resolve to server2 so I could add it in the rdns record then I need your help with this.

Comment: And since you've admitted you are a spammer, i have no incentive to help you.   Additionally, this Q&A area is for PROFESSIONAL networking, not a free help service for those who aren't technically competent.